# c# How can I crop an image to a diamond form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following code to crop my image to an elipse:

```
public static Image CropToCircle(Image srcImage, Color backGround)
{
    Image dstImage = new Bitmap(srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height, srcImage.PixelFormat);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(dstImage);
    using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(backGround))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(br, 0, 0, dstImage.Width, dstImage.Height - 100);
    }
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddEllipse(0, 0 , dstImage.Width, dstImage.Height);
    g.SetClip(path);
    g.DrawImage(srcImage, 0, 0);

    return dstImage;
}
```

But I want this to looks like a diamond shape, how can I do achieve something like the image below?

[image]

Comment: You could make a mask yourself in photoshop and use its transparency to crop.

Comment: @John This is interesting, I never heard of that in a way to "Export mask from photoshop - use that in C#". Is there any tutorial/knowledge reference for that? Thx!

Comment: Draw the image in photoshop or gimp with a transparent background. Load it as a Bitmap, resize it to your Bitmap. Then iterate both at the same time and set the transparency of the your pixels to match that of the mask image. I don't have any references on hand.